# jQuery sticky button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

I have a problem with jQuery scroll and sticky button.

I have this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/wvurtq72/6/)

```
$window.scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var scrollTop = $this.scrollTop();

  if ($buttonFilter.length > 0) {
    if (scrollTop + windowHeight > buttonFilterFullSize) {
      if ($buttonFilter.hasClass('fixed')) {
        $buttonFilter.removeClass('fixed');
      }
    } else {
      if (!$buttonFilter.hasClass('fixed')) {
        $buttonFilter.addClass('fixed');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and it work good when all of Collapse is hidden, but when I open it all, sticky button don't work so good and don't follow when I use scroll.

What can I do to improve my code?

Comment: that's because your variable values should change when you click on the links and open the collapse content. For example `buttonFilterOffset` ( offset top of the button ) changes when you open a text. You need to calculate those variables dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(document).height();` to get the document height instead of window's (browser window) height and you need to put it within scroll event to refresh the value when the accordion expands.

As for the condition you need to total up `scrollTop` and `windowHeight`. `scrollTop` gives you the Y-coordinate and `windowHeight` gives you the window's height, both of them add up will be the `documentHeight`.

You code should be something like below:

```
 $window.scroll(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var scrollTop = $this.scrollTop();
     var documentHeight = $(document).height();
     var windowHeight = $(window).height();

     if ($buttonFilter.length > 0) {
       if ( (scrollTop + windowHeight) === documentHeight) {
         if ($buttonFilter.hasClass('fixed')) {
           //do something....
         }
       } else {
         if (!$buttonFilter.hasClass('fixed')) {
          //do something....
         }
       }

     }
```